# How are machine learning techniques used in automated theorem proving?

Tags: machine-learning, theorem-proving

Logical proof can be viewed as searching for a path that leads from premises to conclusions, where each step is the application of an inference rule. I wonder how machine learning techniques can help find heuristics that limit the search for solutions into a smaller sample size.

Comment: Have you done some research? There's a number of publications on this topic that are accessible. One implementation is http://staff.computing.dundee.ac.uk/katya/ML4PG/